# Overlay a GeoTIFF image with ipyleaflet

Tags: overlay, openstreetmap, jupyter-lab, geotiff

I want to use ImageOverlay function in ipyleaflet by below code, it only shows openstreetmap without geotiff layer, How can I do it?

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, ImageOverlay

m = Map(center=(31, 48), zoom=9)
image = ImageOverlay(url="D:/aa//IDW.tif",
        bounds=((30, 46.1), (32.5, 48.8)))

m.add_layer(image);
m
```

Comment: any experience on this so far?

Comment: You can add only use relative urls to ImageOverlay. Try "./IDW.tif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add relative local paths (as mentioned by @Darwin1871)

Here is a snapshot from [the docs](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/image_video_overlay.html)

[image]

Comment: Looks like local paths are supported now. Updated link to the docs: https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/image_video_overlay.html

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the image into a base64 string:

```python
import base64

with open("D:/aa/IDW.png", "rb") as file:
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(file.read())
    
image = ImageOverlay(
    url="data:image/png;base64," + base64_encoded.decode(),
    bounds=((30, 46.1), (32.5, 48.8))
)
```

Since TIFF images are not supported by many browsers ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)), rather use PNG or JPEG.